# How do I attach this pump head to my Schrader valve?

Tags: pump

[image: Pump Head]

I am such an idiot, but I can't figure out how to attach this pump head to my Schrader valve.  The lever doesn't seem to flip up??

Answer (score 6):

That's a quick chuck commonly found at gas stations. There's no locking mechanism.

You just push the quick chuck head firmly onto the schrader valve and squeeze the air release. Hand pressure alone keeps the valve seated against the chuck. With car tires (see photo below) it's easy as the schrader valve is solidly affixed to the tire rim.  With bicycle tires, it's a bit tricky as the schrader valve isn't fixed and can push into the rim, so sometimes you have to gently push or hold the other side of the schrader valve with your other hand to steady it.

[image: Tire being inflated]

Note that it's VERY easy to overinflate a bicycle tire with these car inflators as they commonly don't have a max pressure setting. I've blown a tire off a rim using a gasoline station quick chuck. So be very careful and fill using only short, quick spurts of air.

Comment: Thanks, but why would the city install this on a floor pump?  How can I hold this on and pump the air in at the same??

Comment: That makes no sense. You'll need at least three hands. My guess is that the old head broke and the Maintenance department put the nearest cheapest one that fit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  Now I have more information I can contact the city (again!) about either changing this head or providing instructions on how to use it if they think that this is somehow usable.